# where to look for on internet for asynctask.java class

Tags: android, android-asynctask

where can i find the official asynctask.java class. I found one and included into my package but at a certain line it couldn't find the reference to Process: Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);

```
                    mWorker = new WorkerRunnable<Params, Result>() {
                        public Result call() throws Exception {
                    // error here
                        Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
                            return doInBackground(mParams);
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: see this both, [first](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/AsyncTask.java) and [second](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/Process.java) , I think you will have to get most of the classes of this [package](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.1_r2/android/os/)

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to take a look at http://code.google.com/p/adt-addons/ it contains **Android Sources**. It's much easier to browse android code right from eclipse with it.

Answer (score 0):

ok. i found it Process.Java was also missing. I copied it from the source. Thanks everyone for helping out.